# az-CosmosDB get all latest records

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I use cosmos DB document and I have a lot of records with structure like below

```
{ 
   datetime: "2022/02/02",// today
   value1: "1",
   .......
}
-------------------------
{ 
   datetime: "2022/02/02",// today
   value1: "2",
   .......
}
---------------------------
{ 
   datetime: "2022/02/02",// today
   value1: "2",
   .......
}
--------------------------
....
--------------------------
{ 
   datetime: "2022/02/01",// old data
   value1: "3",
   .......
}
---------------------------
```

I want to get all the records of today (today is latest data) **with just one query**. is that possible?

*** **Update 1**

First, I try to get latest data by query

> SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.datetime= (SELECT VALUE MAX(c.datetime) FROM c
> )

`SELECT VALUE MAX(c.datetime) FROM c` will return result  `2022/02/02`. But when I execute subquery it return all data. My expected is just data of today (latest day 2022/02/02).

I change from `SELECT VALUE MAX(c.datetime) FROM c` to `SELECT TOP 1 c.datetime FROM c ORDER BY c.datetime DESC` => error.

Is there a query to help me do that?

Thanks,

Comment: Yes possible, depends on how you want to retrieve, is is on the portal or through SDK?

Comment: @Sajeetharan
On portal, when I query
SELECT * FROM c
WHERE c.datetime= (SELECT VALUE MAX(c.datetime) FROM c )
It return all records. So what is the correct query?

Comment: Please *edit your question* to show your query, output, etc. Please don't post things like queries (or additional questions) in comments. Especially important for text that needs to be formatted (such as a sql query).

Comment: Aside from that: It's really important to show the attempt/code you've tried, along with expected vs actual output, errors, etc. In your question, you showed a bit of data, but nothing else. Also, your data shows dates represented in a non-standard way. And, based on your comment, you are mis-using `MAX()` - that's not going to have any idea the input is a date.

Answer (score 0):

I am making an assumption that your data is stored(string) in the same way as you posted in the question, you can write a query like below to get the records for specific date,

```
SELECT * FROM c where STARTSWITH(c.datetime, "2022/2/2")
```

Comment: That matches about 10 different dates: "2022/2/2", "2022/2/20", "2022/2/21"... etc.

Comment: I would suggest waiting for the OP to provide specifics around what they tried. Right now, there's only a snippet of sample data and nothing else, in the question.